# What's the best way to create a percentage value from two integers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have two integers that I want to divide to get a percentage.

This is what I have right now:

```
int mappedItems = someList.Count(x => x.Value != null);
int totalItems = someList.Count();
(int)(((double)mappedItems /(double) totalItems) * 100)
```

This gives the right answer.  But that is a lot of casting to do something as simple as get a percentage between two numbers.

Is there a better way to do this?  Something that does not involve casting?

Comment: Thanks for the great answers!  Votes all around!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

How about just `mappedItems * 100.0 / totalItems` and casting this to the appropriate type?

Comment: Be careful with division by 0 if the list is empty.

Comment: or add an `M` suffix like `* 100M`.

Comment: The original solution allows for values of mappedItems within the full range (Int32.MaxValue / Int32.MinValue). Your solution will cause an overflow for values > (Int32.MaxValue / 100) or < (Int32.MinValue / 100)

Comment: @Eduardo: Definitely! And if the list is empty you can avoid trying to compute `mappedItems` and `totalItems` to begin with. That can be helpful if the computation for `mappedItems` is expensive (in this case it's not, though).

@Frank » This is true, but sometimes readability is a more important concern for maintenance.

Comment: @Jan: What is the `M` suffix?  I have not heard of that.

Comment: @Vaccano: The `M` suffix means a `decimal` literal. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691085%28VS.71%29.aspx .

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was already checking for zero and the rounding does not matter.  This works great!

Answer (score 12):

The right integer-only way to get percentage with proper rounding is:

```
int result = ( mappedItems * 200 + totalItems ) / ( totalItems * 2 );
```

How do we get there? If we do this thing in floating point, it would be `Math.Floor( mappedItems * 100.0 / totalItems + 0.5 )`. We need to transform this formula to be integer-only by multiplying and dividing 0.5 by totalItems, then moving 0.5 * totalItems into dividend, and then multiplying both dividend and divisor by 2 to make fractions go away:

mappedItems * 100.0 / totalItems + 0.5 => mappedItems * 100.0 / totalItems + totalItems * 0.5 / totalItems => ( mappedItems * 100.0 + 0.5 * totalItems ) / totalItems => ( mappedItems * 200.0 + totalItems ) / ( totalItems * 2 ).

At this point the formula is integer-only. When we do integer division, we get floored result, so the integer-only result is equivalent to the mentioned floating-point one.

Answer (score 10):

If you just wanted to avoid the casts, you could write:

```
(100 * mappedItems) / totalItems
```

but that will quickly overflow when `mappedItems > int.MaxValue / 100`.

And both methods round the percentage down. To get correct rounding, I would keep the result as a double:

```
((double)mappedItems /(double) totalItems) * 100
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get a correctly rounded result using only integer operations:

```
int percent = (200 * mappedItems + 1) / (totalItems * 2);
```

By multiplyingby two, adding one and dividing by two, you are effectively adding a half. This makes the integer division do a rounding instead of truncating.

Comment: Your formula isn't right and doesn't work. See my answer for the right formula and explanations.

Answer (score 4):

Well, assuming your counts are smaller than int.MaxValue:

```
int percent = mappedItems * 100 / totalItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use (mappedItems * 100) / totalItems but this would always round down. The method that you have used is better. Why not wrap the code up as a method?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add that as you've got `int`s and want to calculate the percentage (a floating point value) you are going to *have* to do casting. Whether it's explicit as in C# or implicit as in some scripting languages the cast will still happen. It's better to make it explicit.

If you want fewer casts per line of code you could write:

```
double mappedItems = (double)someList.Count(x => x.Value != null);
double totalItems = (double)someList.Count();
double percentage = (mappedItems / totalItems) * 100.0);
```

Though as others have pointed out - check for `totalItems` being 0 (preferably before casting to double) to avoid a divide by zero.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int mappedItems = someList.Count(x => x.Value != null);
int totalItems = someList.Count();
int percent = Convert.ToInt32(complete * 100.0 / total);
```

in this example, you'd get result being "50"

```
int mappedItems = 14;
int totalItems = 28;
int result = Convert.ToInt32(mappedItems * 100.0 / totalItems);
// result is 50
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me.

```
 double percentage = (double) (mappedietms * 100) / totalitems;
```

label6.Text = $@"Health: [{Math.Round(percentage ,1)}]";