# Incorrect calculation

Tags: c#, operators

In C# programming I was working with Operators but I'm stuck in the following error where value of tip and tax are not as expected.

Code of my Console application:

```
class OPerators
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the MealCost");

        double mealCost = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int tipPercent = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int taxPercent = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // calulation Part

        // here i am getting the value of tip is 0.
        double tip = mealCost * (tipPercent / 100); 

        // here also value of tax is 0.
        double tax = mealCost * (taxPercent / 100);  

        double totalCost = mealCost + tip + tax;

        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(totalCost));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

How can I get the values of `tip` and `tax`?

I've tried:

```
double a = (tipPercent /100); 
tip = mealCost *a;
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to create a percentage value from two integers in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124283/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-percentage-value-from-two-integers-in-c)

Comment: `20 / 100` in integer arithmetics is `0`. Switch to `double` consistently. Also note that `decimal` is far better for representing monetary values.

Comment: Please explain how your program is incorrect.  For example, what are the expected results compared to the actual results?

Answer (score 1):

It is to be noted `Decimal` should be used for monetary values.
Regarding your question itself, you can use the code below in order to have the expected results:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the MealCost");

        decimal mealCost = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int tipPercent = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int taxPercent = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // calulation Part

        decimal tip = mealCost * ((decimal)tipPercent / 100m);
        decimal tax = mealCost * ((decimal)taxPercent / 100m); 

        decimal totalCost = mealCost + tip + tax;

        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(totalCost));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You dont need to cast and devide by a decimal. As long as one number isnt int, it will chose the decimal devision.

Answer (score 0):

Change the output of the bracketed calculation to a floating point number using:

```
double tip = mealCost * (tipPercent / 100.0);
double tax = mealCost * (taxPercent / 100.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are dividing integer by 100, which will always return 0 if number is below 100. typecasting tipPercent and taxPercent to double will solve your problem.

```
double tip = mealCost * ((double)tipPercent / 100);
```

hope this helps

Comment: thanks it works , i put double in front of the hole expression of division by 100 .